# How to execute script in Spring Boot application which uses MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application which uses the mongo DB as database. For some reason, I have an inconsistent property in a simple collection. For example, I have a decimal property called "value" and this property has values like "string" and "double" types. So I need to convert the string values to decimal values. What is the best approach to solving it?

is there a framework to run versioned scripts in spring boot?
Can I run a start method to find all items and update all using spring-data?
other options?

Answer (score 0):

I used [mongeez](https://github.com/hzpz/mongeez-spring-boot-starter) and it's working properly.